# Clojure: shortcut for when-let

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

With the following structure one can do a truth-test (f1) and save the result to a locally bound variable a. If the truth test was false, the whole expression returns nil. If it's truthy (not false) the returned value is passed to a second function (f2) and it's result is returned.

```
(when-let [a (f1)]
   (f2 a))
```

Is there a shortcut? I don't need the variable a as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest you can get with the core library is [`some->`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some-%3E)

```
(some-> (f1) (f2))
```

Its behavior differs slightly from `when-let`: Because [`some->`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some-%3E) threads every non `nil` value it also threads `false`. In practice this behavioral difference never occurred to me as a problem because functions that return something you want to pass to another function return `nil` if they got nothing, not `false`.

Answer (score 5):

No, but it's easy for you to write one. We'll call it `bind`, for reasons that don't matter unless you want to read about monads:

```
(defn bind [v f]
  (when v (f v)))

(bind (f1) f2)
```